# Python cursor fetchmany generator

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, keras, generator

I'm working on a keras model and I want to use fit_generator. Therefore I build a generator which loads only a part of the database into the memory:

```
def dbIter(self):
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Select * from BIG_TABLE')

    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(100)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            yield result
```

So that's working good, `fit_generator` needs indefinitely data. So I have to go back to the start and not break the generator. How do I jump back cleanly? (I'm using sqlite3)